# can angularjs project be created using npm?

Tags: angularjs, npm

I was wondering if an angularjs project structure be created using the npm or any other commands.

Like for creating a new angular project we use:

```
ng new application_name
```

For creating a new react app we use:

```
npx create-react-app application_name
```

Can we even use **npm** for creating angularjs project?

I was looking for directory structures for AngularJs and thought it would be nice if there was a simple command for creating a new AngularJs project with the general structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Angular.js` does not have a CLI as some other modern stack, so no one made that functionality and probably no one will never as it is deprecated.

I can think of a better solution like creating a git repository with an Angular.js boilerplate you want to use programatically and clone it instead. If you want to use git you will need to reinitialize the repository but that's not big deal.

You can take a look at [this existing example repository](https://github.com/jbutko/AngularJS-Boilerplate) which would be initialized using this:

```
git clone https://github.com/jbutko/AngularJS-Boilerplate.git
```

You could make your own project boilerplate and use instead of this one.

**EDIT:** Github allows to create your own template repository. [You can check the docs here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-from-a-template)

Comment: can we convert an existing angularJS project to support npm? Please suggest